# How to add field in django admin non related to model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a checkbox in Django Admin that is not related to a field in my model.
Depending on the value of the checkbox, I want to do some extra actions.

```py
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #if checkbox:
        #    do_extra_actions()
        super(DeviceAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

How to add this checkbox in the django admin form for my model `Device` and get the value in `save_model` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first create a `ModelForm` with such extra checkbox:

```
class DeviceModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Then you plug this into the `DeviceAdmin` and inspect its value:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DeviceModelForm
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if form.cleaned_data['extra_checkbox']:
            # do_extra_actions()
            pass
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: It's work well, thank you. Do you know if it's possible to change the order ? I want to add the checkbox at the end of the page

Comment: @darkvodka: if you override the `__init__` of the `DeviceModelForm`, can you use `self.fields['extra_checkbox'] = self.fields.pop('extra_checkbox')` *after* making a call to the super function?